# How to use CreateContext and AppContext in React using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, im trying to import my existing React app with JSX to TSX, but for some reason the AppContext doesnt work like it did was on my JSX:

App.JSX :

```
export interface ContextType {
  cursor: {x: number, y: number},
}

export const AppContext = createContext<ContextType | null>(null);

export default function App() {
  const [ cursor, setCursor ] = useState<ContextType['cursor']>({ x: -100, y: -100 }); // Store the cursor x and y position

...

  return(
    <div id="app" onMouseMove={ updateCursor }>
      <AppContext.Provider value={{ cursor }}>
      ...
```

Cursor.JSX :

```
import { AppContext, ContextType } from "../../App;

...

export default function Cursor() {
    const { cursor } = useContext(AppContext);
```

So it did say, Property 'cursor' does not exist on type 'ContextType | null'.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the property `cursor` does not exist on the type `null` (the initial context value set by your code when you called createContext), even though it exists in `ContextType`.

One way to fix it is to change:

`export const AppContext = createContext<ContextType | null>(null);`

to

`export const AppContext = createContext<ContextType>({ x: 0, y: 0 });`

The above will make the context always have a `ContextType`-compliant value

Alternatively, you can still `useContext(AppContext)`, but you will need to check whether that value is null first. Probably something along the lines:

```
const context = useContext(AppContext);

if (!context) return null; // this really depends on the logic of your component, I'm early returning here just to demonstrate

const { x, y } = context;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the definition of the type in the `createContext`, because you also allow `null` as value, which is not an object with a property `cursor`.

I would define the context with a valid default fallback, e.g.

```js
 export const AppContext = createContext<ContextType>({x:0,y:0});
```

You'll probably don't call `useContext` outside of the ContextProvider, so the value will never be used. But doing it like this, it's guaranteed, that a valid context object is returned.

As an alternative define a special `useAppContext` method to access the context. This also improves readability.

```js
const useAppContext:ContextType = ()=>{
 const ctx = useContext(AppContext)
 if(!ctx) {
   throw new Error("useAppContext must be used within AppContextProvider")
 }
 return ctx
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean and scalable way to do this is to separate this logic in a separate file and define what information will be passed by your application.

For example, I will leave an example of a code that I implemented in an authentication context that I believe could help you. In it, I also use Typescript.

**File: /contexts/auth.tsx**

```
interface AuthContextData {
    signed: boolean;
    user: User | null;
    loading: boolean;
    ...
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextData>({} as AuthContextData);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signed: Boolean(user), user, loading }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

**File: /App.tsx**

```
import { AuthProvider } from "./contexts/auth";

import Routes from './routes';

function App() {

    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <Routes />
        </AuthProvider>
      )
}
```

So, you can access the information inside something that is wrapped by the AuthProvider as follows:

**File: /routes/index.tsx**

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import AuthContext from "../contexts/auth";

import UnauthenticatedRoutes from './unauthenticated.routes';
import AppRoutes from '../routes/app.routes';

import Loading from '../components/Loading';

const Routes = () => {
    const { signed, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (loading) {
        return <Loading />;
    }

    return signed ? <AppRoutes /> : <UnauthenticatedRoutes />;

};

export default Routes;
```

Try applying this to your logic and it will certainly work, as well as improving the quality of your code.